# php cli reading files and how to fix it?

Tags: php

While using PHP cli in ubuntu i got apache as web server i cant read the file which i can while using it in the browser.
And about the error it just shows nothing and the next like i just used this code for my testing purposes :

```
<?
$handle = fopen("testFile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
if(!is_readable($handle)
{
 die("Not readable");
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

How do i fix that ?

EDIT :

After removing the '@' before fopen i got the following error

> fopen(testFile.txt): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/log/ka.php on line 2

Comment: Well, if you put an `@` before `fopen`, it's obviously not going to report any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run your script through CLI, it uses your shell's working directory, in opposition to the file's directory (which Apache hands as the current directory). This is important for you, since your `fopen` call depends on a relative path; and relative paths are resolved relatively to the working directory, not to the script.

To have your script behave like it does with Apache, you either need to `cd /var/www/log` prior to running the `php` command, or add this at the beginning of your PHP script:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```